# D3.js multiple pie chart resizing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm adding D3 pie charts to the SVG Map chart, and anchoring them to city lat + lon coordinates. That's all working fine. I'm struggling to change the size of each pie chart dependent on the 'value' in the data.

Can anyone help me understand how I can change the arc variable for each item which I believe is responsible for the radius of each pie chart? I've tried a number of different approaches that I've found in searches here, but bar rewriting most of my code in order to get the pie charts in, I'm hoping it's possible from here?

Here's the portion of my code that creates and adds the pie charts:

```
// Add piecharts to map
        // I need to implement something like this
        // but not sure how I do that for each pie chart
        // d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(d.value)

        var arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(15),               
            pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .value(function(d){ 
                return d });

          var pies = svg.selectAll('.pie')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'pie')
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
              return "translate(" + projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0] + "," + projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1] + ")";
            });

          var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#3f71b0", "#e11c42"]);


          pies.selectAll('.slice')
            .data(function(d){
                return pie([d.value, d.subset]); })
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            // I think this is where I need to implement a loop
            .attr('d', arc)
            .style('fill', function(d,i){
              return color(i);
            })
            .style("opacity", 1)
            .style("stroke", "#fff")
            .style("stroke-width", "1.5");
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

-dt

Comment: var arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(15) this line sets the radius. inner radius is 0 thats why its a pie chart, Set to some 5 it will be a donut. Hope that helps

Comment: Hi @Dragon_Slayer , that part is fine, I'd like to change the radius of each pie chart (there's 85 in all) using the 'value' value in my data. So hopefully there will be 85 different shaped pie charts anchored to city positions on my map. Any ideas on that at all? I'm stuck :(